# PHP Curl Fatal error on posting Json array on Localhost

Tags: php, curl, xampp

I use the folowing Php/ Curl code to post an array of data to a webpage. When on my web hosting this is working fine without errors. When testing in local/xampp responds with the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: curl_setopt_array(): Argument #2 ($options) must contain only valid cURL options;

> curl_setopt_array(Object(CurlHandle), Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 88

I am looking everywhere but I can't find why this is not working on xampp/local and it has no issues on my hosting..

All help is welcome.

The code:

```
$PostCurrentAccInfo = json_encode($CurrentAccInfo);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://external.site/UpdateAccounts.php',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 1,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_POST => true,
      CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'),
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $PostCurrentAccInfo, **// Line 88**
    ));
    $DatabaseResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Try curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have an added the value as next array key instead of the value for CURL_HTTPHEADER:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json'),
```

Comment: What do you mean? I am new to this, can you explain what i need to do?

Comment: well, exactly what i posted. you have a `,` instead of a `=>`

Comment: Thank you. Never thought it could be a typo as it is running fine on the hosting